# Fieldset values not displaying properly -django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

models.py for **member** table.

```
class Member(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='anything')
```

I want to display fullname, email, companyname and company number in **profile** page.

---

models.py for **profile** table

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=60)
   contactno=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   worknumber=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   timezone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Instead of manually entering the values(data) for fullname, contactno, companyname and email in the fieldset, It should fetch from **member** table and displayed here.
Can we use **OneToOneField** or **foreign key** here, to implement this concept.
Thanking You in Advance. You will be highly appreciated, if you could suggest the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for `user` (in your exmaple the `member`) and `profile`, we use `OneToOne` field to connect each other, namely, each user has only one profile.

As the `Profile` model belongs to the `User` model, we need to put the `OneToOneField` in the `Profile` model.

For example:

```py
class Member(models.Model):
   fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='anything')

class Profile(models.Model):
   worknumber=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   timezone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
   member = models.OneToOneField(
        Member, verbose_name=_("member"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

And in your `views.py` or templates you can refer to profile by dot notation like `member1.profile.timezone`. Please note that the `related_name` attribute determines how you can refer to a `Profile`, if you change `related_name` to `file` for example, then you should use `member1.file.timezone`.

One note for your implementation on `Member` model, not sure if you have another `User` model, but for customization, usually we inherit from `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` (for more customization). Those default base models already have some fields like `email` and `password` which you do not need to implement in your own model.

Another suggestion is that in Python we usually use Snake case for naming a `variable` or a `function`, like `full_name`, `company_name`, and Pascal Case for naming a `Class`, like `UserProfile`.

Check [this example](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/) and the official doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) for a custom `User` model implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for you time and effort to explain me these things.